# Running a persistent IRC client over SSH

Tags: ssh, proxy, irc

I'm looking for advice on how to run a persistent IRC client from a server and allowing me to connect from different computers.

I want the IRC client to stay connected, even when I'm bringing my laptop from work to home. I prefer to run the client on my laptop, proxying over the server. Is this possible?

An alternative is to SSH into the server and tmux the connection, but I would need to use a non-graphical IRC client?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**I've got 3 suggestions, I think you'll like number 2. best.**

---

1.
My preferred solution is to install 'screen' then run irssi inside. You can ssh in and reattach to the screen or....

Load the proxy module: http://www.irssi.org/documentation/proxy You'll then be able to attach your preferred client.

In my opinion irssi is better than any gui.

---

2.
However, I think you want [Quassel](http://quassel-irc.org/). Its a graphical version. It lets you detach clients from the server as you want:

> one (or multiple) client(s) can attach to and detach from a central core that stays permanently online -- much like the popular combination of screen and a text-based IRC client such as WeeChat, and similar to (but much more featureful than) so-called BNCs
>
> **Re-attaching your client will show your IRC session in the same state as you left it** in (plus whatever happened while you were gone), and this even when you re-attach from a different location.

(emphasis added)

---

3.
And as it says, BNCs (bouncers) will let you attach *any* client to them, but will be much more limited in features, for example scrollback. Check out BNC/ZNC etc. etc.

Answer (score 8):

As you already suggested, the best option is to use `irssi` as your IRC client, which you will run in `screen` to keep running even after you disconnect from `ssh`.

So you go like this:

1. Install `irssi`
2. Install `screen`
3. Deploy `ssh`
4. Connect to the server with ssh
5. Run `screen` (without any further parameters)
6. Then run `irssi`
7. Press `CTRL+A` followed by `CTRL+D`. This detaches `irssi` into the `screen`
8. Now you can disconnect from `ssh`. Your IRC will keep running.
9. When you connect back and want to get to the `irssi` running in `screen`, simply type `screen -r`, to resume

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be looking for a BNC if you're wanting to keep your client local instead of on the server. You might find [ZNC](http://en.znc.in/wiki/ZNC) useful.